# Manual (or handbook) to/for/of <product>?

Tags: sentence-construction, prepositions

If I want to advertise a technical product's manual:

> <Product> v1.2 Documentation
>
> Official manual **for** <product> - the fastest, greatest <thing>

is **for** the right preposition?

**to** seems simply wrong, but could be used in a claim like:

> The easy way to <product>

(long version: *"The easy way to learn how to use <product>"*)

**of** feels like it's okay, but expresses that the manual is part of <product> (as in possession).

Are there other ways to say this?

**for** seems like a good choice, because the second half of my sentence refers to <product>, not its handbook, and **for** doesn't diminish the understandability of this.

Comment: I think "of" also can be used to imply "associated with"

Comment: I don't get the meaning of the second one. Could you write whole sentences?

Comment: Manual to Tardis app / manual for Tardis app / manual of Tardis app (Tardis app is made-up).

Answer (score 1):

While it is not unheard of to use "*to*" or "*of*" in similar phrases

> A big book *of* crosswords
>   The definitive introduction *to* gardening

(both can be books, texts, or a set of instructions), yet the noun "*manual*" is more often used with the preposition "*for*", I think.  Google gives >80M results with "**manual for**", >30M with "**manual of**", and less than 17M with "**manual to**" (how much demonstrative those are, is open to debate, of course).